# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{A}=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{A}=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra  of subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

I am new to this terminology and so please correct me if I am wrong. What I understand is that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the smallest sigma-algebra generated by the set class $\mathcal{A}.$ I know that $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{J})$ where $\mathcal{J}=\{I:\text{if I is an interval}\}.$ So $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{J}.$ Now we have to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{J})=\sigma(\mathcal{A}).$ The usual way to do this would be by double inclusion but if I choose a set $Q\in \sigma(\mathcal{J})$ then I don't know how it looks so I am not sure how I can go about the proof. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: It suffices to show that any interval $I$ is included in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Does this help in the proof $(a,b)=(-\infty,a]\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty,b+1/n]$?

Comment: Since $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{J}$, if you show $\mathcal{J} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, this implies $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{J}) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Yes, that shows $\mathcal{J} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Note that the other direction is then straight forward, as $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{J}$.

Comment: Firstly, you need to know that the set $(-\infty,a]$ is measurable. To prove $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is  Borel σ−algebra, take the infinte intersection of those intervals of the given form, $(\infty,a]=(-\infty,a) \cup \{a\}$ and 
$(-\infty,a)=\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( { - \infty ,a + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} $.